# Tomcat plugin classes JAR grails-plugin-tomcat-7.0.47.jar not found eroor while running grails project

Tags: tomcat, grails, plugins, jar

I am using grails-2.3.3 and java-7 while running my application from IntelliJ Idea I'm getting this error....

```
| Error Tomcat plugin classes JAR grails-plugin-tomcat-7.0.47.jar not found
| Running Grails application
Error: Could not find or load main class org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

and the code in my buildconfig.groovy file is like this....

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'

}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
     build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
    compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"
    // compile ":activiti:5.12.1"
    // compile ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.4" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.4"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
}
}
```

i'm using ubuntu machine and intelliJidea version is 12.
do anyone having idea whats the problem with this i'm new to grails and try to googling out this problem but not able to found any help.

Comment: Have you tried running a "grails clean"?  I would also blow away project temp files in /.grails/2.3.3/projects/your_project and /.grails/ivy-cache if that exists (I'm not sure if Grails 2.3.3 is still using Ivy or not out of the box). Let us know if you do that and still get the same.

Comment: i did grails clean and blow away project temp files but the problem is still there.

Comment: have you tried a "grails refresh-dependencies"